# Celery Beat process crashes after nslookup failure

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I'm using Celery 3.1.19 with scheduled tasks. I start the process like so:

```
celery beat --app=my_app.celery.app:app --pidfile=/usr/local/celerybeat.pid --schedule=/usr/local/celerybeat-schedule -l INFO
```

I've had a couple occurrences where the celery process terminates after an nslookup failure. This causes future scheduled tasks to not run. Eventually I notice and restart celery beat.

As far as I can tell the hostname it's trying to lookup is my RabbitMQ host. The nslookup failures are temporary. The hostname is correct and evidently there was a blip in name resolution. Ideally that would not crash the process and instead it would retry until it the hostname lookup succeeded.

Questions:

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. Is there a common way to ensure that the scheduler keeps running?
3. Do people have a system to watch the process and restart if it crashes?

Stack trace:

```
 Message Error: Couldn't apply scheduled task ping: Error opening socket: hostname lookup failed
 File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
 sys.exit(main())
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
 main()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
 cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 770, in execute_from_commandline
 super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 311, in execute_from_commandline
 return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 762, in handle_argv
 return self.execute(command, argv)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 694, in execute
 ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 315, in run_from_argv
 sys.argv if argv is None else argv, command)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 377, in handle_argv
 return self(*args, **options)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 274, in __call__
 ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/beat.py", line 79, in run
 return beat().run()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 83, in run
 self.start_scheduler()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 112, in start_scheduler
 beat.start()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/beat.py", line 473, in start
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/beat.py", line 221, in tick
```